# Karma.js is taking more than 30 seconds to create test after hitting the run command

Tags: selenium-webdriver, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

On hitting the command - node_modules.bin\karma start js\tests\karma.conf.js the test takes more than 30 seconds to start.

I have checked the automation logs for any clue but apparently no logs are created before the test is being created. Tests are getting queued for no reason. I have tried the same on CI/CD like GitHub Action but the result is same. Below is the config file code:

```
`const webDriverConfig = {
  desktop: {
    hostname: 'hub.lt.com',
    port: 80
  }
}`
```

```
`  config.concurrency = 1,
  config.port = 9876,
  config.hostname = 'localhost.lt.com',
    Object.keys(browsers['lambdaTest']).map(key => {
      browsers.lambdaTest[key].base = 'WebDriver'
      browsers.lambdaTest[key].build = 'HYE'
      browsers.lambdaTest[key].project = 'Bootstrap'
      browsers.lambdaTest[key].config = webDriverConfig.desktop
      browsers.lambdaTest[key].user = ENV.LT_USERNAME
      browsers.lambdaTest[key].accessKey = ENV.LT_ACCESS_KEY
      browsers.lambdaTest[key].console = true
      browsers.lambdaTest[key].network = true
      browsers.lambdaTest[key].pseudoActivityInterval = 5000 // 5000 ms heartbeat
    })
  plugins.push('karma-webdriver-launcher', 'karma-jasmine', 'karma-jasmine-html-reporter')
  config.customLaunchers = browsers.lt
  config.browsers = Object.keys(browsers.lt)
  reporters.push('kjhtml')`
```

browsers.js

```
`const browsers = {
  lt: {
    chromeWin10: {
      browserName: 'Chrome',
      browserVersion: '109',
      'LT:Options': {
        platformName: 'Windows 10'
      }
    },
    firefoxWin10: {
      browserName: 'Firefox',
      browserVersion: '109',
      'LT:Options': {
        platformName: 'Windows 10'
      }
    },
    chromeWin10Latest: {
      browserName: 'Chrome',
      browserVersion: '108',
      'LT:Options': {
        platformName: 'Windows 10'
      }
    },
    firefoxWin10Latest: {
      browserName: 'Firefox',
      browserVersion: '108',
      'LT:Options': {
        platformName: 'Windows 10'
      }
    }}`
```

How to reduce these 30 seconds taken?